# Problems with Kinect webserver and speech support

Tags: c#, javascript, kinect, speech-recognition, kinect-sdk

We are developing a web app for Kinect for Windows and we would like to add speech recognition support.

We have modified the webserver code [as showed in the kinect for windows blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kinectforwindows/archive/2013/10/02/using-kinect-webserver-to-expose-speech-events-to-web-clients.aspx) and added javascript code to manage speech events in the web app that is processing speech properly.

Our problem is related to Kinect set-up: when the web app loads, javascript code performs a "postConfig" that now includes the xml grammar for the voice commands where are working with. This function takes longer than before (when no speech recognition support had been added) to complete and in the meanwhile, Kinect elements "freeze" (handPointer cursor does not move, userviewer does not refresh). Because of this, each time the user navigates to a different url within the application (and so, postConfig is performed again) the app keeps "hanged" for a few seconds.

Anybody with the same problem? Can it be resolved?

EDIT: No code was provided since we are working with the project attached to the kinect blog post I linked. Our web app is not the same, but this problem also happens with the sample web app in the project.

EDIT2: Results of "basic debugging":
Javascript code needs to call postConfig method in API. This method include this code:

```
this.postConfig = function (configData, error) {
    [omitted code for arguments number and type check]
    console.log("ajax start");
    ajax("POST", stateEndpoint, JSON.stringify(configData),
    function(response) {
        console.log("ajax complete");
        if (!response.success && (error != null)) {
            error("semantic failure", response);
        }
    },
    (error != null) ? function (statusText) { error(statusText); } : null
    );
}
```

"ajax" function configures and performs a XMLHttpRequest (open, onload=[...], send)

Console message "ajax start" always is printed before "freezing", then a few seconds pass (not always, time is variable), then "ajax complete" is printed and Kinect interface is responsive again. 
Since XMLHttpRequest is POST there is no processing in the "onload" event, just message printing.

Comment: Show some code?... This question will be removed in no time if code is not provided or at least that some effort in doing so is shown.

Comment: Why should it be removed? The scenario described above can be repeated by anybody with Kinect SDK and the project in the blog I linked. Besides I don't know which parts of the code are "freezing" the Kinect streams.

Comment: Then I think that your question is too broad to have a clear answer.

Comment: have you tried the basic debugging method? you claimed that adding the speech recognition support cause your app to freeze for awhile on start up, can you at least try and isolate the general area(within the new code) that cause the freeze? simply putting some log lines in it and find out which section took the longest.

Comment: That might be true, but maybe some developers have tried to add speech support to web apps (as official blog tells how to do it) and found the same problem.

Comment: @JackyCheng: I had done so and I edited the question, I hope it made clearer what is happening.